# in sharepoint 2010 my site, disable subsite creation and personal document library

Tags: 2010, my-site

I'm being asked to disable the subsite creation ability and "personal document library" that exist under the Content tab in My Site. I did some searching, but don't see any info on this. Is it possible, and if so what is the best way?

Comment: If you don't want to allow your users to use the MySite, then why do you create them? The profile/social features don't require the users to be able to create Personal Sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is not meant to function as such, because the actual My Sites concept revolves around the User being Site Collection Administrator by default. What you could do is rely on Feature Stapling  (attach it to SPSPERS#0 site templates) to activate your own feature which could then perform operations post-provisioning to:
1. Either remove default Site Collection Administrator and assign a custom permission level
2. Remove the actual Library as soon the site collection gets provisioned.

Of course you could act and do a lot of other customizations at that stage.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solved this yet check this blog post: http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=5489bebf-bd8d-4a6f-995b-3a0a456796f6&ID=101&Web=316c15c2-6bc0-464f-bda1-7ba96b4ba453

Worked like a charm to me.